# Can't solve this exercise

Tags: geometry

Given:
$\triangle ABC$. 
$MN$ - midsegment and $M \in AC; $ $N \in BC$.
The perimeter of ABMN is 22 $P(ABMN) = 20$
$AB = 10$

Find the perimeter of $\triangle ABC$

All I was able to do i get that MN = 5 (from that MN is midsegment => MN = $\frac{AB}{2}$)

Comment: What is "$P(ABMN) = 10$"?

Comment: Hint: Since $MN$ joins the medians of $AB$ and $AC$, and you know the perimeter of $ABMN$ as well as the lengths of $AB$ and $MN$, you should be able to figure out $AM+BN$, from which you should be able to solve the problem.

Comment: No P(ABMN) = 22, AB(side of the triangle) is = 10

Comment: Whats P(ABMN)?? You have two perimeters for same figure??

Comment: AM + BN = 7 but I don't see how his helps me. 
P.S. I had a mistake in my question P(ABMN) = 22

Comment: Then edit it,no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more elaborate hint: we know

1. $22 = P(ABMN) = AB + AM + BN + MN$,
2. $AB = 10$, and
3. $MN=AB/2, AM=AC/2, BN=BC/2$.

Can you see how to get $AB+AC+BC$ from this?